# Is it possible to use something like an IBOutlet array?

Tags: iphone, uilabel, interface-builder, iboutlet, iboutletcollection

I have a top list view in my current iPhone app, that's populated by code. I've assembled the view using Interface Builder, so it contains lot of `UILabel`s.

Obviously I wouldn't like to have `name1`, `name2`, etc. outlets in my class, but prefer a `name[10]` array.

Is it possible to do so, and connect each item to the appropriate label (or any other interface builder like view)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot do it in IB, but you can create an array in your `init` method and add all your labels to it.

BTW, you can set some tag to each label and define macro to access it. smth like

> ```
> #define NAME[TAG] (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:TAG]
> ```

Answer (score 22):

You can of course do this with interface builder, the keyword is `IBOutletCollection`. What it does is basically an NSArray out of multiple interface builder outlets.

```
IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *myLabels;
```

So the next thing would be connecting your labels in interface builder and then you can use the array to access all labels at runtime.

Comment: This must be a new feature of the Interface Builder and Xcode, isn't it?

Comment: @Shinjin: I can't give you an exact date or release when this feature became available, but I know that its there for a bit longer now (at least a year old).

Comment: I read elsewhere that this was added as of iOS 4. However, you cannot rely on the order of IBOutlets (or couldn't; not sure if it has been fixed by iOS 8 or not).

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to create an array of outlets an connect it with IB Elements (Here is example of `UIView`, you can use `UILabel` also):

- Create an array of IBOutlets
- Add multiple UIElements (Views) in your Storyboard ViewController interface
- Select ViewController (In storyboard) and open connection inspector
- There is option 'Outlet Collections' in connection inspector (You will see an array of outlets there)
- Connect if with your interface elements

-

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var collection:[UIView]!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using outlet collections, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356612).