# Creating a reference to a UIImageView from a string

Tags: xcode, nsstring, uiimageview

I have a series of UIImageViews which are created in IB. I want to show and hide these depending on some button presses. I currently have a method which says if 1 is pressed then hide 2,3,4 then if 2 is pressed then hide 1,3,4. This works but I am trying to improve my code for an update.

My background is actionscript so I'm not sure if what I am trying to do is the right thing.

I basically want to evaluate a string reference to UIImageView, in AS I would use eval(string).

The method I am using is to create a string from a string and a number, so I get "image1". All works, but then I need to evaluate this into a UIImageView so I can update the alpha value.

Firstly is this possible and if not how should I be doing this? I'm starting to think that having this set up in interface builder maybe isn't helping?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably not a good way to work.  What you want is an array of imageViews.  Then you just need a numeric index, and you can go through the array of imageViews hiding everything that doesn't have the chosen index.

But how do you get an array of imageViews?  See [How to make IBOutlets out of an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356612/how-to-make-iboutlets-out-of-an-array-of-objects)  It explains how to use IBOutletCollection.

If you have a separate button for each view, put those into an IBOutletCollection too.  That way you can have something like this:

```
- (IBAction) imageButtonPressed:(id) sender;
{
    // The sender is the button that was just pressed.
    NSUInteger chosenIndex = [[self imageButtons] objectAtIndex:sender];
    for (NSUInteger imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < [[self imageViews] count]; imageIndex++)
    {
        // Hide all views other than the one associated with the pressed button.
        if (imageIndex != chosenIndex)
        {
            [[[self imageViews] objectAtIndex:imageIndex] setHidden:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [[[self imageViews] objectAtIndex:imageIndex] setHidden:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

If you really, really need to associate the string `image1` with an imageView, you can construct an `NSDictionary` associating your controls with unique string identifiers for later lookup.  NSDictionary is powerful, but I'm drawing a blank on reasons why this would be needed.

```
NSMutableDictionary *viewLookup;
[viewLookup setObject:[[self imageViews] objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"image0"];
[viewLookup setObject:[[self imageViews] objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"image1"];
[viewLookup setObject:[[self imageViews] objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"image2"];

[viewLookup setObject:[[self imageButtons] objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"button0"];
// ...
// Can now look up views by name.
// ...
NSString *viewName = @"image1";
UIView *viewFound = [viewLookup objectForKey:viewName];
[viewFound doSomething];
```